# Why does the Interlocked.Add() method have to return a value?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
public static int Add(ref int location1,int value)
```

I was trying to use the Interlocked.Add(ref int location1,int value) method to add to a number in an atomic manner in multi-threading scenario. But I got a question to myself: why does the method return the location1 value again? Instead we could directly use the variable which is passed as "ref".

Some pseudo code below:

```
int a = 6;
int b = 7;

// some thing else

Interlocked.Add(ref a, b);

// Use the variable 'a' here.
```

Comment: [If you're going to use an interlocked operation to generate a unique value, you need to use it before it's gone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/25/10413997.aspx).

Comment: I would recommend reading up about the C++11 memory model, and why it has all the little details they put into it.  It's not C# (C# came before the C++11 memory model), but it does a remarkably good job of showing just how incredibly unintuitive atomic operations are unless you understand some of the hardware limitations atomic operations are designed to work with.  If you don't puke when you read about MEMORY_ORDER_CONSUME and kill_dependency, you're ready to do atomic operations (I still get a little bile in the back of my throat, myself).

Comment: Follow that up with something C# specific like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863136.aspx.  The most important two insights I can give you though are (1) the moment you begin doing shared-memory multithreaded programming you need to change your attitude from "values of variables are stable until something makes them change" to "values of variables are constantly changing unless something keeps them the same", and (2) you simply do not understand this stuff well enough to write bug-free programs. The more I learn about threading, the less confident I am that I'm getting it right.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because the variable `ref a` could change "again" before `Interlocked` returns (or even after it returns and before you use `a`). The function instead returns the value it calculated.

Example:

```
int a = 5;

// on thread 1
int b = Interlocked.Add(ref a, 5); // b = 10

// on thread 2, at the same time
int c = Interlocked.Add(ref a, 5); // c = 15

// on thread 1
Thread.Sleep(1000); // so we are "sure" thread 2 executed 
Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // just to be sure we are really reading a
bool x1 = (b == 10); // true
bool x2 = (a == 15); // true
```

Comment: if 2 threads read value of a exactly the same time, wouldn't b and c = 10?

Comment: @MovsarBekaev No. The `Interlocked.Add` does a read + add that are guaranteed to be atomic, so there is no "time" for the second `Interlocked.Add` to read a spurious value.